# MySQL: If after select(count(*) for Dropping column if exists

Tags: mysql

I already read multiples post about drop a column if exists on the forum as

```
if exists 
(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME='tablename' AND COLUMN_NAME='columname' )
   ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name
```

But, unfortunately, none give a results on MySQL 5.7. It's because i try this:

```
if (select count(*) from information_schema.columns
  where table_name = 'XXXX'
  and column_name = 'XXXX')=1
 then
ALTER TABLE `XXXX`.`XXXX` DROP COLUMN `XXXX`;
end if;
```

Please can someone explain me how to solve this issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you writing a stored procedure here?

Comment: Ok @tadman this problem has been solved through a function. Thanks

Comment: If you did figure it out, it's worth adding an answer to this with your working solution. That can help other people with a similar problem. Sometimes that person is you in the future when you forgot how you fixed it.